# jQuery.inArray returns always -1

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I have the following shoping list

[image]

and I want each time the user click on the trash can the product to be deleted from the list.
So I have this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

var selectedproducts = new Array(); //List of selected products



$("#add_product_button").button();
$("#add_product_button").click(function() {


  //Add some products to selectedproducts
      //Omitted for clarity
selectedproducts[i]=document.getElementById("autocomplete_text_field").value;
         thesi=jQuery.inArray(document.getElementById("autocomplete_text_field").value,selectedproducts);  
         var row=$('<div class"productsclass" style="height:50px; background-color:#E36D84; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; border-style:solid; border-color:#DB4865; id='+rowID+'" ><label style="position:relative; top:10px; left:2px; font-size:20px">'+selectedproducts[i]+'</label><input  style="position:relative; left:2px; top:10px; width:20px;" type="text" name="Quantity" value="1"><img class="delete" id="'+rowID+'" src="http://b.dryicons.com/images/icon_sets/handy_part_2_icons/png/128x128/recycle_bin.png" height="22"  width="22" style="position:relative; top:10px; float: right;"></div><br>'); 
       rowID++;
       $("#productstable").append(row);
       i++;
       console.log("Thesi: "+thesi+" Timi:"+document.getElementById(thesi).value);

});



 //Delete products
$(document).on("click", "[class*='delete']", function(s) {

    thisID = $(this).attr('id'); //find items parent
    console.log("ThisID: "+thisID);
    console.log(jQuery.inArray(thisID,selectedproducts));//find item's position in the selectedproducts
    selectedproducts.splice(thisID,1);
    $(this).parent().hide("explode", 1000);
    $(this).parent().remove();//delete item
    console.log("Size:"+selectedproducts.length);
    console.log(selectedproducts);


}); 


});
```

The problem is that `jQuery.inArray` always returns -1. The correct product is deleted from the UI but from the selectedproducts Array

HTML:

```
  <div id="maindiv" class="maindiv">
<input id="autocomplete_text_field">
<button id="add_product_button">Add product</button>
</div>

<div id="supplier">
<form name="frm1" action="http://localhost/tddd27/index.php/auth/session">
<input type="image" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/fb_supplier.png" />
</form>
</div>


<div id="ProductsDiv" class="ProductsDiv" hidden="true">
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>Shopping List</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="fragment-1">
 <form action="#" id="productstable" name="productstable">
<p></p>
</form>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what my be the problem?

Comment: Why `[class*='delete']` and not simply `.delete`?

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the shopping list as well?

Comment: @limelights - And that's a problem because... :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I had something setup wrong, sorry for that!

Comment: (1) `selectedproducts[i]` suggests we're in a loop, but there's no loop, and `i` is not initialized! Same for `rowID`. (2) `document.getElementById(thesi)` suggests `thesi` is an element id, but it's set to the value returned by `$.inArray()` ie an integer. (3) Why use `document.getElementById()` when jQuery is clearly available? (4) Why repeated `document.getElementById("autocomplete_text_field").value` when you could assign the value? (5) Are `thesi` and `thisID` intentionally global and if so why? I suggest, there are many things to fix here.

Answer (score 0):

Your asking for

```
thesi=jQuery.inArray(thisID,selectedproducts);
```

But

```
selectedproducts
```

is not defined. Or am i missing something?

Comment: Same with `jQuery.inArray(document.getElementById("autocomplete_text_field").value,pnames` :-?

Comment: is defined in the same function. If I do `console.log(selectedproducts)` the array is printed in the console. I will post all the function

Comment: I am struggling with the exact same issue. It seems that inArray and indexOf is not huge fans of numeric arrays or requests. using a keyword instead of a number seems to work much better.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I think it's ok now. Code omitted for more clarity

Comment: @AvraamMavridis - You've hidden the part where you add items to `selectedproducts`. If we don't know what `selectedproducts` contains, how can we say why the lookup fails?